# Assembly local variable makes crash

Tags: assembly, local

I have the following function written in nasm syntax:

```
global _denseToDenseAddRelAVX_nocache_32_linux
_denseToDenseAddRelAVX_nocache_32_linux:

push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp

push    eax
push    ecx
push    edx
push    edi
push    esi

; edi: address1     [ebp + 8]
; esi: address2     [ebp + 12]
; edx: address3     [ebp + 16]
; ecx: count        [ebp + 20]
; xmm0: lambda      [ebp + 24]
; xmm2: relTolerance [ebp + 32]

mov     edi, [ebp+8]
mov     esi, [ebp+12]
mov     edx, [ebp+16]
mov     ecx, [ebp+20]
movlpd  xmm0, [ebp+24]
movlpd  xmm2, [ebp+32]

mov     eax, ecx
shr     ecx, 2
and     eax, 0x03

vzeroupper

vmovupd  ymm5, [abs_mask]

sub     esp, 16 ; make space for 2 doubles

movlpd  [ebp - 8], xmm2
movlpd  [ebp - 16], xmm0  ; <------ THIS LINE IS WRONG

add     esp, 16

pop    esi
pop    edi
pop    edx
pop    ecx
pop    eax

mov     esp, ebp
pop     ebp
ret
```

If I delete the line movlpd  [ebp - 16], xmm0, my software works, but if not, the program crashes. If I use 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 and 14 instead of 16, my softtware works again. Of course, I use the last 9 lines for debugging, i.e. I return from the function earlier. What is the problem with this code?
I am in 32 bit protected mode environment, and I call this function from c++.

Comment: You're overwriting the stack locations where ESI, EDI, etc.. were pushed.

Comment: Did you use a debugger to identify where the program crashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing data to `[ebp - 8]` and `[ebp - 16]` is bad here because it will destroy the value of saved registers, and writing to `[ebp - 16]` is especially bad because it will destroy callee-save register `edi`.

Not tested, try avoiding breaking the saved registers like this:

```
movlpd  [ebp - 28], xmm2
movlpd  [ebp - 36], xmm0
```

Answer (score 1):

where you `make space for 2 doubles`, you probably mean to store relative to `esp` rather than `ebp`, but in any case you immediately throw the two values away by cleaning up the stack. you need to rethink how you're going to return the values to the caller.

wait, just noticed the part about the last 9 lines. what you probably want is:

```
movlpd  [esp], xmm2
movlpd  [esp+8], xmm0
```